# .htaccess permanent redirect of query string to directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, slider, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to use .htaccess redirect to solve my slider post issue on my wordpress site.

My current "slider post" URL is as follow leading to a blank post:
http://mysite.com/?slider=post-slug

I want to redirect to the real post location with an identical "post slug":
http://mysite.com/news/post-slug

How do I set my rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this (above whatever wordpress rules you may have) in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slider=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /news/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok, after adding the above, the slider image no longer goes to the blank "slider post".

Comment: when i click on the image now it reloads my homepage and the same URL with http://mysite.com/?slider=post-slug still appears in the url bar. technically, i need it to go to http://mysite.com/news/post-slug/

Comment: @marvivostudio one of your other rules is doing that.

Comment: not sure what it could be... here's my .htaccess file http://pastebin.com/E1xVwZ6d

Comment: @marvivostudio This line `RewriteRule ^$ /news/%1? [L]`, you are missing the `R=301`.